# Partially failed Android decompile contains a weird int: 65536(0x10000, float:9.18355E-41)

Tags: java, android, decompiling, apktool

I have decompiled an application using APKTool and JadX and I'm trying to manually restore a few spots that didn't decompile correctly. So far it's going slow but steady and I've fixed all of the other ones. But I'm a bit stumped by the following line:

```
r2 = 65536(0x10000, float:9.18355E-41)
```

I know it's supposed to be an `int` because that's the signature of the function I'm passing it into. But how do I deduce the value of this constant?

I can only find other decompile dump by Googling it, no clues for it's true value or how to calculate it.

Comment: I'm just guesstimating, but it seems like the decompiler wasn't sure about the type of `r2`. I think the value is 0x10000 (or just 65536 decimal). The float value is just those same bits interpreted as a float.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimSauer that makes total sense. It looks like a valid value for the function I'm passing it into. But it's hard to validate to me.

This decompilation has been an interesting trip inside of a compiled program for sure so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Joachim Suaer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) already said it's just a constant value that the compiler is unsure of if it was meant to be an int or a float.